# How to summarize `Number of days since first date` and `Number of days seen` by ID and for a large data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

The dataframe `df1` summarizes detections of individuals (`ID`) through the time (`Date`). As a short example:

```
df1<- data.frame(ID= c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 Date= ymd(c("2016-08-21","2016-08-24","2016-08-23","2016-08-29","2016-08-27","2016-09-02","2016-09-01","2016-09-09","2016-09-01","2016-09-10")))

df1

   ID       Date
1   1 2016-08-21
2   2 2016-08-24
3   1 2016-08-23
4   2 2016-08-29
5   1 2016-08-27
6   2 2016-09-02
7   1 2016-09-01
8   2 2016-09-09
9   1 2016-09-01
10  2 2016-09-10
```

I want to summarize either the `Number of days since the first detection of the individual` (`Ndays`) and `Number of days that the individual has been detected since the first time it was detected` (`Ndifdays`).

Additionally, I would like to include in this summary table a variable called `Prop` that simply divides `Ndifdays` between `Ndays`.

The summary table that I would expect would be this:

```
> Result
  ID Ndays Ndifdays  Prop
1  1    11        4 0.360 # Between 21st Aug and 01st Sept there is 11 days.
2  2    17        5 0.294 # Between 24th Aug and 10st Sept there is 17 days.
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Can we see your attempt please?. Also your `Ndifdays` is unclear

Comment: Hi Sotos, I think that for `Ndifdays` is enought with `unique()`, but I don't know how to summarize the number of days between first and last detection per individual (`Ndays`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve using various summarising functions in  `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Ndays =  as.integer(max(Date) - min(Date)), 
             Ndifdays = n_distinct(Date), 
             Prop = Ndifdays/Ndays)

#     ID Ndays Ndifdays  Prop
#   <dbl> <int>    <int> <dbl>
#1     1    11        4 0.364
#2     2    17        5 0.294
```

---

The `data.table` version of this would be

```
library(data.table)
df12 <- setDT(df1)[, .(Ndays = as.integer(max(Date) - min(Date)), 
                       Ndifdays = uniqueN(Date)), by = ID]
df12$Prop <- df12$Ndifdays/df12$Ndays
```

and base R with `aggregate`

```
df12 <- aggregate(Date~ID, df1, function(x) c(max(x) - min(x), length(unique(x))))
df12$Prop <- df1$Ndifdays/df1$Ndays
```

Comment: FYI, `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object.`

Comment: @Sotos Actually, it works for me without any error. But I guess you mean to wrap `as.integer` for `Ndays`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes that's what it implies but it's weird it doesn't error out for you

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by 'ID', get the `diff` or `range` of 'Date' to create 'Ndays', and then get the unique number of 'Date' with `n_distinct`, divide by the number of distinct by the Ndays to get the 'Prop'

```
library(dplyr)    
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Ndays =  as.integer(diff(range(Date))), 
         Ndifdays = n_distinct(Date), 
         Prop = Ndifdays/Ndays)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     ID Ndays Ndifdays  Prop
#  <dbl> <int>    <int> <dbl>
#1     1    11        4 0.364
#2     2    17        5 0.294
```