# How to calculate number of hours from a fixed start point that varies among levels of a variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

The dataframe `df1` summarizes detections of different individuals (`ID`) through time (`Datetime`). As a short example:

```
library(lubridate)

df1<- data.frame(ID= c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 Datetime= ymd_hms(c("2016-08-21 00:00:00","2016-08-24 08:00:00","2016-08-23 12:00:00","2016-08-29 03:00:00","2016-08-27 23:00:00","2016-09-02 02:00:00","2016-09-01 12:00:00","2016-09-09 04:00:00","2016-09-01 12:00:00","2016-09-10 12:00:00")))

> df1
   ID            Datetime
1   1 2016-08-21 00:00:00
2   2 2016-08-24 08:00:00
3   1 2016-08-23 12:00:00
4   2 2016-08-29 03:00:00
5   1 2016-08-27 23:00:00
6   2 2016-09-02 02:00:00
7   1 2016-09-01 12:00:00
8   2 2016-09-09 04:00:00
9   1 2016-09-01 12:00:00
10  2 2016-09-10 12:00:00
```

I want to calculate for each row, the number of hours (`Hours_since_begining`) since the first time that the individual was detected.

I would expect something like that (It can contain some mistakes since I did the calculations by hand):

```
> df1
   ID            Datetime Hours_since_begining
1   1 2016-08-21 00:00:00                    0
2   2 2016-08-24 08:00:00                    0
3   1 2016-08-23 12:00:00                   60 # Number of hours between "2016-08-21 00:00:00" (first time detected the Ind 1) and "2016-08-23 12:00:00" 
4   2 2016-08-29 03:00:00                  115 
5   1 2016-08-27 23:00:00                  167 # Number of hours between "2016-08-21 00:00:00" (first time detected the Ind 1) and "2016-08-27 23:00:00" 
6   2 2016-09-02 02:00:00                  210
7   1 2016-09-01 12:00:00                  276
8   2 2016-09-09 04:00:00                  380
9   1 2016-09-01 12:00:00                  276
10  2 2016-09-10 12:00:00                  412
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this similar to your previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931816/how-to-summarize-number-of-days-since-first-date-and-number-of-days-seen-by ? Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Thanks @markus. I don't think so. I used the same dataframe since I don't think the double effort is necessary, but the calculation is completely different. In the commented post I looked for a summary on one hand, and on the other hand I worked with days and not with hours. Here the tricky point is how to refert to the first time that the individual was detected... With the script of the mentioned post I can do what I want here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
library(tidyverse)
# first get min datetime by ID
min_datetime_id <- df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(min_datetime=min(Datetime))
# join with df1 and compute time difference
df1 <- df1 %>% left_join(min_datetime_id) %>% mutate(Hours_since_beginning= as.numeric(difftime(Datetime, min_datetime,units="hours")))
```

Comment: you can directly do it without join. `df1 %>%
  arrange(ID, Datetime)  %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(hours = as.numeric(difftime(Datetime, first(Datetime), units = "hours")))
`